# Windows Phone 7 (Nokia Lumia 800) - Problems accessing marketplace

Tags: lumia, store, nokia-lumia-800

I just got a lumia 800(won it) and I have not yet connected to provider but wanted to install some apps.

Every-time I try to go to the marketplace I run into this problem

Marketplace Error
We're sorry, but we can't complete your request right now.

try launching marketplace again. If the problem continues, check back in a  little while, or try restarting your phone.

Error code: 805a0193

I also tried to see if I can get windows phone 7.8 on it so I installed the zune software but it tells me this

[image]

Comment: Are you using WiFi? Have you tried rebooting your router?

Comment: A lot of microsoft services went down for a bit because of an azure failure - http://xbox.firstorfast.com/2013/02/23/xbox-live-windows-azure-experience-extensive-outage/

Comment: I've had problems with my Lumia 800 as well. I could log in with my live ID, its already synchronized, but when I try marketplace, it asks me to log in again and it says Error. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

You must create a Microsoft account in order to do this.

You may also need a SIM Card in but I can't be sure.

Comment: You can use the marketplace without a SIM card.

Comment: It all of sudden worked a few hours later. Must have been a marketplace problem.